# Zeros of "nearby" holomorphic functions

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-zeta

I would  appreciate help in how to show that

On a compact subset of {$z \in \mathbb{C}: 1/2 < \Re (z) < 1$}:

"Given a holomorphic function with an isolated zero, any "nearby" holomorphic function will also have a zero."

This statement is from an article on Zeta Function Universality, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeta_function_universality.

I would presume that "nearby" implies that if $z_0$ is a zero of $f$ and you represent $f$ as a power series around $z_0$, then you can also represent the "nearby" $g$ also as a power series about $z_0$.

Thus you would have

$$f(z) =\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(z-z_0)^n = (z - z_0)^k\sum_{n=k + 1}^\infty a_n(z-z_0)^n$$

where $f$ has a zero of order $k$ at $z_0$, and $a_{k + 1}$ is the first coefficient $\neq 0$.

Then the assertion would imply that you can similarly represent the "nearby" $g$ by

$$g(z) =\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n(z-z_0)^n = (z - z_0)^l\sum_{n=l + 1}^\infty b_n(z-z_0)^n$$

Assuming this is correct so far. I would appreciate help proving the statement.

Thanks very much.

EDIT: This is the relevant part of the article:

"Note that the function f is not allowed to have any zeros on U. This is an important restriction; if you start with a holomorphic function with an isolated zero, then any "nearby" holomorphic function will also have a zero. According to the Riemann hypothesis, the Riemann zeta function does not have any zeros in the considered strip, and so it couldn't possibly approximate such a function."

Comment: If "nearby" means "close to", then use Rouché's theorem.

Comment: @Etienne I do think you're correct. If you want to write it as an answer, I will accept it. Either way, thanks,

Comment: I think it's OK as a comment. Glad that it helped you!

Comment: @Etienne Please make your comment an answer so this question will drop off the unanswered questions list.